# Maximum Y in a rotate ellipse with a, b and phi

Tags: conic-sections

We have major axis, minor axis and the phi between major axis and y axis in a rotated ellipse. 
How can we find the maximum y?

Comment: And the phi that y become maximum

Comment: What background do you have? If you rotate your question, you're asking for a point on a "standard" ellipse where the tangent line is perpendicular to the line $y=(\tan\phi)x$ ...

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that $\phi=0$ gives the maximum $y$. If you think vectorially, the position vector in direction of the major axis is longest. If you take a different vector and *then* project it, it gets shorter and shorter again.

Comment: Dear Ted, IT is not correct. see the following link and the picture.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91132/how-to-get-the-limits-of-rotated-ellipse

Comment: Background: I have a elliptical orbit for a rotating shaft that shows the position of the rotor center at one turn. I have the phase that rotor is farthest from the center (a,b, phi). But I want to find the phase in which the y become maximum to use it for balancing the rotor (finding influence coefficients of the rotor). Because the sensor in located in the y direction.

Comment: What I've said is correct if everything is 2-dimensional. But your description here sounds like you're thinking 3-dimensionally.