# how to obtain peripheral recangle of arbitrary ellipse?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose have arbitrary ellipse with center $(x,y)$ and its radius $(a,b)$. I want obtain rectangle that sides tangent of peripheral ellipse. the below image describe issue :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations we use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Related: ["The locus of two perpendicular tangents to a given ellipse"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33520/409).

Comment: Also: Search Math.SE for ["ellipse director"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=ellipse+director) to find numerous questions and answers related to an ellipse's ["director circle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle) (the locus of points where two perpendicular tangents meet).

Comment: See another answer of mine [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889450/extrema-of-ellipse-from-parametric-form/1890278#1890278).

Comment: please give me more explanation to find my unknown values specified in image.

Comment: i found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91132/how-to-get-the-limits-of-rotated-ellipse) solution works fine.