# Can a figure inside a circle be seen at right angle from any point on the circle?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, paradoxes

> A convex, closed figure lies inside a given circle. The figure is seen from every point of the circumference at a right angle (that is, the two rays drawn from the point and supporting the convex figure are perpendicular). Prove that the center of the circle is a center of symmetry of the figure.

Firstly does the question mean for the figure to be two-dimensional? Otherwise do there exist such figures in $3$D (in other words if the $3$D figure doesn't intersect the circle)? In $2$D, the only such object I can think of is the diameter of a circle, but I was wondering if there are more.

Comment: The diameter isn't the only solution in two dimensions. See this five-year-old question: ["The locus of two perpendicular tangents to a given ellipse"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33520/409). I suspect that the question intends that the figure be two-dimensional, but your 3D variant is rather intriguing ... I can think of one solution (for an appropriate interpretation of "supporting"): a sphere whose radius matches that of the circle, and which is tangent to the circle's plane at the circle's center.

Comment: @Blue For the $2$D variant, are the director circle and the diameter the only two solutions?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the Director Circle theorem says that the solutions would be the family of ellipses with major and minor radii $a$ and $b$, such that $a^2 + b^2 = r^2$, where $r$ is the radius of the circle. (You can think of the diameter as the case $a = r$, $b = 0$ ... which may not technically be allowed, because the "supporting" property degenerates at the diameter's endpoints.) I don't happen to know if there are other 2D solutions.

Comment: @Blue Is this statement true: If the center of the circle surrounding a convex, closed figure is a center of symmetry of the figure, then the figure is seen from every point of the circumference at a right angle (that is, the two rays drawn from the point and supporting the convex figure are perpendicular).

Comment: @user19405892 No, take any smaller concentric circle except for the one with $1/\sqrt{2}$ of the original radius. It will be seen from every point at the same angle, but not the right angle.

Comment: @Conifold Why does the question mention that the figure is closed if it would be impossible otherwise?

Comment: It is not impossible, but may lead to trivial variations, like removing finitely many points, etc.

Comment: @Conifold Give me an example where it would be possible for it not to be closed because otherwise one cannot define something to be seen at a right angle.

Comment: Take a smaller circle and remove 5 points from it, at arbitrary locations, it makes no difference for how it is seen.

Comment: @Conifold There will have to be a supporting line to those points you have drawn somewhere from a point on the circle so it does make a difference.

Comment: Supporting line may not be defined (depends on whether one defines it to necessarily have a common point with the curve, this makes sense for closed sets but not in general), but it makes no difference to how the curve is *seen*. It will be seen subtended by the same angle even after the point is removed.

Comment: @Conifold But how do you see something without a boundary? Seeing something doesn't really make sense for things that aren't closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38993/discussion-between-conifold-and-user19405892).

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many figures like that.

Let $p(\theta)$ be any smooth periodic function of period $2\pi$. It is known that
the necessary and sufficient condition for such a function $p(\theta)$ to be the
[support function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function) of a convex set $K$ is
$$p(\theta) + p''(\theta) > 0 \quad\text{ for all }\;\theta$$

The boundary of the convex set $K$ is given by the parametrization:

$$\begin{cases}
x &= p(\theta)\cos\theta - p'(\theta)\sin\theta,\\
y &= p(\theta)\sin\theta + p'(\theta) \cos\theta
\end{cases}
$$
If you pick a function $p(\theta)$ which satisfies an additional constraint
$$p(\theta)^2 + p\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 = 1$$

then for every $\theta$, the pair of tangent lines at $\theta$ and $\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}$ intersect at some point on the unit circle. Since they are perpendicular to each other, the angle subtended by $K$ at that intersection will be a right angle.

As an example, pick any $\alpha \in [0,1)$ and consider the function
$\displaystyle\;p(\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{1+\alpha \cos(2\theta)}{2}}$.
It is easy to check
$\displaystyle\;p(\theta) + p''(\theta) = \frac{1-\alpha^2}{\sqrt{2}(1 + \alpha\cos(2\theta))^{3/2}} > 0$ for all $\theta$. 
This give us a convex set bounded by the curve
$$\begin{cases}
x(t) &= \frac{1+\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1 + \alpha\cos(2\theta)}}\\
y(t) &= \frac{1-\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{1 + \alpha\cos(2\theta)}}
\end{cases}$$
With help of an CAS, one can simplify this to the ellipse
$\displaystyle\;\frac{x^2}{1+\alpha} + \frac{y^2}{1-\alpha} = \frac12$.
This is equivalent to the director circle mentioned by others in comment.

For a more complicated example, one can try something like
$\displaystyle p(\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{1+\beta\cos(6\theta)}{2}}$
where $\beta \in [0,\frac{1}{17})$ instead. This will give you a figure
that looks like a hexagon with the edge curved outward.

Comment: So there are other solutions other than the director circle?

Comment: That makes me wonder if there are other solutions besides director circles.

Comment: Isn't it sort of redundant to say that the figure is closed? Otherwise it wouldn't be able to be seen at right angles from the circle.

Comment: @user19405892 In analysis of convex figures, it is common to assume we are dealing with objects that is closed. Sometimes one even assume the object has non-empty interior. A whole class of result is based on that. Since this class is large enough to contain a lot of interesting cases. People just stuck with this assumption whenever they quote results (to avoid any foreseen pathological case )

Comment: This question makes no sense if the figure is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

It does imply that everything is in the plane, otherwise it wouldn't say "figure" or talk about two rays "supporting" it, it would be a cone in 3D. Diameter is a good suggestion due to the [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales'_theorem) but it won't work because the condition is violated at the endpoints of the diameter. One obvious solution is a concentric circle of smaller radius. Inscribe a square into the original circle, and then inscribe the smaller circle into the square. Rotating the square around the smaller circle shows that it will be seen at $90^\circ$ angle from any point on the original one. By the Pythagorean theorem the radius of the smaller circle is $1/\sqrt{2}$ of the larger one's for this to happen.

This construction may generalize. At first, it seems that the inscribed circle is the only such figure, but it also at first seems that the circle is the only [curve of constant width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width), while in fact there are infinitely many of them. In this case the set of points from which a compact convex figure is seen at a constant angle $\nu$ is called its $\nu$-isoptic. The $\pi/2$-isoptic is called orthoptic. The OP question is equivalent to asking if a circle is the only convex figure having a circular orthoptic. According to [Kurusa's Is a Convex Plane Body Determined by an Isoptic?](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13366-011-0074-2)

> "*[In 1950 Green proved](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077476114) that if the $\nu$-isoptic of a convex body D is a circle, then D must be a disc provided $1-\nu/\pi$ is an irrational or rational number with even numerator in its lowest terms. If the numerator is odd, then there are continuum many bodies not even similar to each other with that circle as their $\nu$-isoptic*".

Since for $\nu=\pi/2$ we have $1-\nu/\pi=1/2$, this is the case of a continuum of non-similar solutions. According to Green, Ernst Strauss noticed earlier that a family of them is easy to construct classically: inscribe a rectangle into a circle, and inscribe an ellipse into that rectangle with its axes equal and parallel to the sides of the rectangle. Then it can be proved that the circle is the orthoptic of the ellipse. These ellipses interpolate between the insquared circle described above, and the circle's diameters, which are their degenerate limits, and "almost" orthoptics. Green constructs more general solutions by using [support functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function) of convex figures.

Comment: At least for the Reuleaux triangle, the statement "Such figure will be seen at $90^\circ$ angle from any point on the original circle circumscribing the square" is not true.

Comment: fix the triangle rigidly relative to what. if you fix the triangle to the square, the when you rotate the square, you also rotate the triangle. if you fix the triangle to the circle, when you rotate the square, you don't keep seeing the triangle at right angle. I've once set the 2nd case up in GeoGebra and verify the angle does change.

Answer (score 0):

Let the given outside circle pass through the origin. Then power of a circle from origin to a circle

$ (x- h)^2 + y ^2 = R^2 $ is:

$ h^2  -  R^2  = T^2$

And the subtended angle at pole is:

$ 2 \tan^{-1} \left (\dfrac{R}{T}  \right)$

If the above should be $\pi/2,$ then $ R= T, h = \sqrt 2 R $

Thus in the plane the radius of inside circle locus equals length of tangent, inside circle has radius $ R= h/ \sqrt 2,$ which exists as a unique envelope between the perpendicular tangents.

In  3D,likewise by rotational symmetry, the required surface locus is a sphere of $ R= h/ \sqrt 2.$ where horizons for an observer on the given circle is the set of *small* circles of latitude $45^{0}$.