# Given an ellipse, find the equation of the set of all points from which there are two tangents to the curve whose slopes are reciprocal.

Tags: calculus

> Given an ellipse $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1,$ where $a\not=b,$ find the equation of the set of all points from which there are two tangents to the curve whose slopes are (a) reciprocals and (b) negative reciprocals.

First I let $P(c,d)$ outside the ellipse,then assume the linear equation: $y=(x-c)+d;$ second, according to the problem, the line must touch the ellipse, so substitute $y$ for the equation of ellipse to get the intersection, then let $D(\text{discriminant})=0.$
After all of this, I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: Why don't you determine the point pairs on the ellipse first and then determine the intersection of the tangents. Express the ellipse as a y = function and then take the derivative and solve for dy/dx = c and 1/c.

Comment: Seems like there’s something missing from your equation of a line.

Comment: where was  first case a)  $ m_1m_2= +1$ answered?

Comment: @Narasimham Fair point. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33528/265466) can be adapted for that case.

Comment: But how adapted?  There should be a solution preferably with a sketch.

Comment: @Narasimham Agreed. I’ve voted to reopen.