# Set of points from which tangent lines to given hyperbola are perpendicular.

Tags: analytic-geometry, tangent-line

Find set of points from which start two perpendicular tangent lines to hyperbola $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Tangent lines to a hyperbola are $y=mx+\sqrt{a^2m^2-b^2}$ and $y=mx-\sqrt{a^2m^2-b^2}$. Two lines $y=a_1x+b_1$, $y=a_2x+b_2$ are perpendicular if $a_1a_2=-1$.

What I want to achieve is circle $\{x^2+y^2=a^2-b^2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question, after one sign-change, is here:
[The locus of two perpendicular tangents to a given ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33520/the-locus-of-two-perpendicular-tangents-to-a-given-ellipse).

I particularly admire @Blue's answer. although to apply it in this case will require that you parameterize the hyperbola with $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ rather than sines and cosines.